# How do I add jar files to the Classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm on `Windows` and I've tried the `-classpath` under `javac` to no avail. Also tried moving the jar to the src directory, but java file still won't compile. Trying to do a simple import of httpclient in the script.

```
   import org.apache.http.client.*;
```

Comment: Post what you add to the classpath and your directory structure. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: Can you provide more information like the entire javac command, source/lib organization, etc?

Comment: Do you really want to add jars to the **JDK**? Maybe you mean to the compilation classpath?

Comment: *"tried the `-classpath` under `javac` to no avail."*  Then your question should be "How do I make -classpath under javac work?".  ***Do not add 3rd party Jars to the JRE (or JDK).***

Comment: Theres no reason to move the jar under the `src` directory, because youre not compiling the jar, youre using it to compile `.java` files, which are indeed under `src` directory. What exactly is the missing class? are you sure it is in the jar youre using? could be a dependency of that jar

Comment: that will do please :D on the question.."How do I make -classpath under javac work?". puzzled why the classpath won't add httpclient-4.0.1.jar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install your JDK and *leave it alone*.  Do *not* copy .jar files into your JDK folders!
2. I'd recommend getting an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, if you don't already have one.
3. I would set up a new project, create or import your source, and set a class path for the project.
4. If that doesn't work, please tell us:

   a) your OS and version

   b) your JDK and version

   c) your IDE

   d) cut/paste the EXACT error message

   e) cut/paste the relevant code

Answer (score 11):

The `-classpath` command line argument (to both `java` and `javac`) expect that you will list *specific JAR files* (and/or "exploded" directories containing class files). This is unlike the Windows/UNIX `PATH` environment variable which just lists directories containing executables.

So for example, if you want to compile `com.example.Foo` that depends on `lib/bar.jar` you might use the following incantation:

```
javac -classpath lib/bar.jar com/example/Foo.java
```

But my guess is that you are also getting a specific error message, and knowing that error message would be useful in helping you further.

Comment: Using httpclient-4.0.1.jar. No matter how I link it in the classpath my java file won't compile. I'm getting no symbol errors all related to java unable to locate the package. I'm wondering if the import syntax in my java file needs to reflect the package I'm using is not a part of the jdk installation?

Comment: But you haven't said what your error message is yet. "When I run `javac ...` I get the following error: *whatever*". If you aren't getting any errors, then nothing is wrong...Unless you are expecting something different (in which case: What were you expecting to see that you didn't see?)

Comment: I'm getting no symbol errors from any of the classes referenced from httpclient.jar in my java file. such as, "cannot find symbol, class defaulthttpclient()"

Comment: If you aren't getting any errors, then it sounds like it is working. What makes you think that it isn't working?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your entire console interaction there. We need to see your full command line (what you typed) and all of the output that `javac` printed to the console.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Having a new bizarrer problem now. Now that my java file has been compiled correctly courtesy of Netbeans and the classpath/jars issues settled, I'm getting NoClassDefFound Errors when I run my signed applet, though the java file originally built fine with all the needed imported classes of HttpClient. I added all of HttpClient's dependent lib/jars to the applet archive="" syntax but still the java console gives NoClassDefFound errors. There's a separate thread on that here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341467/java-upload-applet-request/10354260