# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while loading from ClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: while loading this class "fol.Classname" like this

```
        classLoader.loadClass("fol.Classname");
```

this class(Classname.class) present in jar(location at /home/user/abc.jar) file in folder "fol". 
while my project at /home/user/Download/Workspace/..
Kindly correct me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the jar to your classpath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386869/how-do-i-add-jar-files-to-the-classpath for running via command line. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse for adding jar to eclipse build path.

Comment: thanks it solves my problem